# How to play mp4 video with multiple audio tracks - Android

Tags: android, flutter, video-player

I have a problem with Android playing mp4 video file with 2 audio tracks(voice and music) at the same time. I have no problems with iOS, it works fine, video + both tracks play by default with no extra configuration. But android playing the video only with one audio track.

Im using the [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) package and I know that this package uses ExoPlayer for Android, but I'm not even sure if its possible to play 2 audio tracks at the same time. Maybe some configuration. But I only found how to do it natively.
Also i found it in the documentation https://exoplayer.dev/track-selection.html:

> A track is ‘supported’ if the Player is able to decode and render its samples. Note that even if multiple track groups of the same type (for example multiple audio track groups) are supported, it only means that they are supported individually and the player is not necessarily able to play them at the same time.

So right now im not even sure if it is possible. Anyone here with the same problem/experience?

I do not have much experience with audio and video so I would be grateful if you suggest some other solution to play a video file with 2 tracks(voice and music)

Thank You in advance!!!